# query for databases and privileges

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, nsuserdefaults, privileges

ok.. i am using sql server 2008... i want a sql query for finding different databases created by a particular login user??? for eg. lets say user1 has created databases db1 and db2. and user2 is created databases db3 and db4.. than the query should give result db1,db2 for user1 and db3,db4 for user2...

also i want query for getting the privileges of a particular user???

Comment: common.... some one help me.... tell me how to find privileges of a particular user??? plz help me...

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think of is the current owner, which is very often the creator of a database.  You can query that like:

```
select  db.name
,       l.name
from    sys.databases db
join    sys.syslogins l
on      db.owner_sid = l.sid
```

To query for a comma-separated list per user, try:

```
select  l.name
,       stuff(db.list,len(db.list),1,'')
from    sys.syslogins l
cross apply
        (
        select  db.name + ','
        from    sys.databases db
        where   db.owner_sid = l.sid
        for xml path('')
        ) db(list)
where   db.list is not null
```

Comment: thanks for replying... but this will give all the databases with the dbowner name.... but i want all the databases created by a particular user??? plz give me this query... also query for finding privileges of a user...

Comment: good..... but can you modify your query so that i get all the databases created by a particular user in different rows and only databases created by that user not all the databases...

Answer (score 0):

well I don't know why do you need to query the user owner for each database 
but I hope this help you :
SELECT name, SUSER_SNAME(owner_sid)
FROM   sys.databases

SUSER_SNAME() well retireve the user name

Comment: thanks for replying... but this will give all the databases with the dbowner name.... but i want all the databases created by a particular user??? plz give me this query... also query for finding privileges of a user.